# Invoking a Remote .bat file over http

Tags: java, python, http, batch-file, remote-access

I have a .bat file on a remote machine. I want to invoke it through http call. I dont want to make any changes on the remote machine. Is there a way to do it using java and http?

```
String command = "cmd /C start C:/Users/abc/Desktop/test.bat";
Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
Process pr = rt.exec(command);
```

The above works good to invoke a .bat file on local machine. I would not mind considering other ways too, but invoking it through http would be the first choice.

EDIT:
I am using paramiko to do this now. However,I am unable to run the remote commands on the command prompt.

```
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()

print "Enter the IP address"
ip = raw_input("ip>")
print "Enter the username"
user = raw_input("username>")
print "Enter the password"
pwd = raw_input("password>")

ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.connect(ip, username=user, password=pwd, allow_agent = False)
print "connection successfull"
i, o, e = ssh.exec_command("echo test") # example command
s = e.read()
if s: # an error occurred
    raise RuntimeError, s
result = o.read()
print result
```

Somehow it says *AllowDesktopAccess failed*

Answer (score 4):

You need a service on the remote machine, for example an http server that is configured to run this script on demand (eg via cgi) or an ssh server you can connect to to issue the command.

Since you're using windows (I assume) then PsExec may be the service you need.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553